# react-bootstrap: using tabs with different message

Tags: javascript, reactjs, tabs, react-bootstrap

I am trying to display a different message based on the tabs. For example, the first tab should say, "SUCCESS! This is the first tab," while the second tab should say, "FAILED! Nope, this is not the first tab. Try again".

So far, my result shows both tabs to display the same message. I am not sure why that happens. I know my style is different, but I want to understand how the react-bootstrap tabs are working with a fix.

The folder contains four files to show the program. Please help me to understand better so I can become a good programmer. Thanks so much!

**index.js**

```
import React from "react"l
import { Tabs, Tab } from "react-bootstrap"
import Tab1 from "./Tab1";
import Tab2 from "./Tab2";

const MessageTab = () => {
return (
     <div>
         <Tabs defaultActiveKey={1} id="uncontrolled-tab-example">
               <Tab eventKey={1} title="Tab 1">
                    <Tab1 />
               </Tab>
               <Tab eventKey={2} title="Tab 2">
                    <Tab2 />
               </Tab>
         </Tabs>
     </div>
     );
     };

export default Tab
```

**Tab1.js and Tab2.js** (Both of them have same structures but the parameters are different)

```
import React from "react";
import TabComponent from "./TabComponent";

const Tab1 = () => {
      const tabs = "a1";                                  // For Tab2, const tabs = "a2"
      const test = "SUCCESS!";                             // For Tab2, const test = "FAILED!"
      return (
           <div>
              <h1>Hello World 1!</h1>                     // For Tab2, <h1>Hello World 2</h1>
              <TabComponent tab={tabs} temp={test} />    
           </div>
      );
      };

export default Tab1;
```

**TabComponent.js**

```
import React from "react";

const TabComponent = (tab, temp) => {
      return (
            <div>
              {tab === "a1" ? 
                 <p>{temp} Yay! This is the first tab</p>                      // temp for a1 is SUCCESS!
              :
                 <p>{temp} Nope, this is not first tab. Try Again</p>          // temp for a2 or other is FAILED!
              }
            </div>;
};

export default TabComponent;
```

**My result...**

```
Click first tab = Failed! Nope, this is not first tab. Try Again       // Desired output: Success! This is the first tab
Click second tab = Failed! Nope, this is not first tab. Try Again      // This is a correct result.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access passed `props` inside the component by:

1. Using `props` as the argument `const TabComponent = props => {..}` and accessing `props.tab`, `props.temp`
2. Using destructuring `const TabComponent = ({ tab, temp }) => {..}` and accessing `tab`, `temp`